# makefile missing separator

Tags: makefile, compilation

I have a  makefile (provided by third party) which gives the following error

```
Makefile:108: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The line in question is the following if statement....  any ideas? have tried various replacing tabs with spaces and not got very far at all...

```
if have_sdl
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/dgraphics.cc
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/SDL_lines.cc
        include_HEADERS += $(srcdir)/utils/SDL_lines.h
else
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/dgraphics_nosdl.cc
endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
ifneq ($(have_sdl),)
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/dgraphics.cc
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/SDL_lines.cc
        include_HEADERS += $(srcdir)/utils/SDL_lines.h
else
        libiulib_a_SOURCES += $(srcdir)/utils/dgraphics_nosdl.cc
endif
```

This checks if have_sdl is non empty (meaning defined to TRUE, yes, 1 or something other than empty string)

Answer (score 5):

If there is no space between ifeq and opening of bracket then also it causes the same warning.

it should be ifeq ()

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any make dialect that allows `if` keyword.  The code you cited is neither POSIX make, nor GNU make.

Examples of working syntax include:

```
ifdef have_sdl
... (rest is the same)
```

and

```
ifneq ($(have_sdl),)  #not equal to empty string
... (rest is the same)
```

.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the `makefile-mode` in `emacs` highlights whitespace syntax errors with red.  Try loading the Makefile in emacs to see if the error is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC (it's been a while) that if/else is a GNU makeism.  If you are not running GNU make then this may well fail.   Solution is to install GNU make.

Comment: Yes - it is laden with GNU make-isms and not using GNU make would come up with that error.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen problems like this caused by blank lines that aren't blank - they contain tabs or spaces. Clearing out all whitespace on the blank lines may solve it.

*Edited to add*: Upon rereading your question, I see that this may not be your particular problem given the line number and code you posted, but it could be a problem for others so I will leave my answer.